# Sum of a PHP dynamic column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

I would like to have the sum of the 4th column of a table, and I dry miserably.

My controller:

```
public function ticket()
{
    $cmdbars = DB::table('bars')
             ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')
             ->get();

    return view('bar_iframe', compact('cmdbars'));
}
```

My view :

```
<table>
@foreach($cmdbars as $cmdbar)

<tr>
    <td>
        {{ $cmdbar->la_qtt }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ $cmdbar->la_denom }}
    </td>
    <td class="txtr">
        {{ number_format($cmdbar->le_tarif_bar/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
    </td>
    <td class="txtr">
        @php
        $sum_produit = $cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt;
        @endphp
        {{ number_format($sum_produit/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach

<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <div class="total_cmd">
            {{-- HERE, I would like the sum of the 4th column --}} €
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm looking for a day and I'm blocking on this problem,
Thanks for your help

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be working:

```
{{ number_format($cmdbars->sum(function($el) {return $el->le_tarif_bar * $el->la_qtt; })/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

(assuming you are using  Laravel 5.3.+ where Query builder is returning collection of elements - method [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum) is used here)

Also I don't see any point in using:

```
@php
$sum_produit = $cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt;
@endphp
{{ number_format($sum_produit/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

Use:

```
{{ number_format(($cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt)/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

instead. Using PHP in Blade (or generally in views) is bad practice and should be avoided if possible.

**EDIT**

Personally I would use Eloquent for this and create `Bar` model and get bars like this:

```
$cmdbars = Bar::orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get();
```

In `Bar` model I would add accessor:

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
   return $this->le_tarif_bar * $this->la_qtt;
}
```

and then in view instead of:

```
@php
$sum_produit = $cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt;
@endphp
{{ number_format($sum_produit/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

I would use:

```
{{ number_format($cmdbar->price/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

and to get sum I would use:

```
{{ number_format($cmdbars->sum('price')/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

Comment: Very high level of coding, too high for me ;)
Works perfectly.
Thanks

Comment: @BossCOTIGA Glad I could help. If it solved your issue, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collection::sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum) with a callback in your controller and pass the result to the view:

```
$cmdbars = DB::table('bars')
         ->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')
         ->get();

$total = $cmdbars->sum(function ($cmdbar) {
    return $cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt;
});

return view('bar_iframe', compact('cmdbars', 'total'));
```

Then you can use `{{ $total }}` where ever you need it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Add each result to `$total` variable:

```
@php
    $sum_produit = $cmdbar->le_tarif_bar * $cmdbar->la_qtt;
    $total += $sum_produit;
@endphp
{{ number_format($sum_produit/100, 2, '.', ' ') }}
```

Display `$total`:

```
<div class="total_cmd">
    {{ number_format($total/100, 2, '.', ' ') }} €
</div>
```